# Docker compose up not starting up

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose to build a docker container. But the problem is whenever I run docker-compose up, I get this error: `app_1 | /usr/bin/python3: No module named app.server` .

P.S. I'm following [this](https://github.com/itielshwartz/sanic-nginx-docker-example).

My docker-compose.yml is:

```
app:
  restart: always
  build: ./app
  expose:
    - "8000"
  volumes:
    - /usr/src/app/static
  env_file: .env
  command: bash -c "cd /usr/src && APP_SETTING=.env python3 -m app.server"

nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./nginx/
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - /www/static
  volumes_from:
    - app
  links:
    - app:app
```

My app/Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
.
#Install Packages
.
WORKDIR /
```

The folder structure looks like:

```
my-sanic-app
├── app
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── quality
│   │   ├── data.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │    
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── server.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── index.html
│   └── utils
│       ├── helper.py
│       └── __init__.py
├── docker-compose.yml
├── nginx
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── sites-enabled
│       └── my_project
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: You aren't copying any files in, the syntax for relative volumes is: `./app:/usr/src/app/static`  You are not defining where to copy files into the container from

Comment: Let me try to invoke this in my app/Dockerfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not copying the python files into the image. The example that you are following, uses the image `python:3.6-onbuild` as a base image for the app.

The `python:3.6-onbuild` consists of the following:

```
FROM python:3.6-jessie

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ONBUILD COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
ONBUILD RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ONBUILD COPY . /usr/src/app
```

In particular the [ONBUILD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#onbuild) instruction triggers execute when building the child image, which is that app in your case. Thus if you are building a new Dockerfile make sure to add the equivalent of those instructions, that is:

```
COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app
```